# Grails defaultPackage ignored?

Tags: grails

When I use create-controller on the command line or in IntelliJ, defaultPackage is ignored. Instead, the controller (or service, etc.) is placed in '@artifact.package.path@':

```
| Enter a command name to run. Use TAB for completion:
grails> create-controller ThingController
| Created grails-app/controllers/@artifact.package.path@/ThingController.groovy
| Created src/test/groovy/@artifact.package.path@/ThingControllerSpec.groovy
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug in my code or Grails, perhaps because I moved config from application.yml to application.groovy:

```
grails{
    profile = 'web'
    codegen{
        defaultPackage = 'com.madeupname.web'
    }
    spring {
        transactionManagement {
            proxies = false
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe there's a typo I'm blind to? I'm using Grails 3.1.7 on JDK 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you define the property in `grails-app/conf/application.yml`.

```
---
grails:
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: com.madeupname.web
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your reply. I was under the impression from your talk and the docs (which describe YAML as "an alternative format") that you could put everything in application.groovy, and I know others are attempting this. Is that not the case? If so, is there a definitive list of config params that must be present in application.yml in order to take effect?

Comment: I wouldn't describe YAML as an alternative.  If I said that in one of my talks then I mis-spoke.  I would consider Groovy an alternative as YAML is the default.  It appears that there is a problem with this particular setting (possibly others) being defined in `application.groovy`, at least in some contexts.  The sample I showed above is a simple workaround.  If there are things that don't work in `application.groovy`, feel free to file an issue and we can take a look.

Comment: Sorry Jeff, you and the docs made it clear YAML is the default, but it sounded like a lot of people were preferring application.groovy. And that "alternative format" wording is straight from the docs, which combined led me to believe everything would work there. I'll add an issue for this, maybe just the docs need a correction. Thanks again.